# Multiple simultaneous POST request, without sending any if one or the other fails

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs

So I want to send 2 post requests together but I want it so that if any of the 2 requests fails (unexpected error for example), none of the requests actually goes through.
This is assuming the 2 post request are separate function on the backend (i.e: 2 separate endpoint).

I have searched and found some questions relatively similar, but all of the solutions wouldn't cancel both requests if one failed, and a lot of them are using what seem to be deprecated functions (`mergeMap`, `forJoin`, ...)

### Attempt

I have tried multiple options:

#### Map a request in another request:

```
this.service.postFunction1(body1).pipe(
  map(()=>this.service.postFunction2(body2).subscribe(
    res=>{
      /** Stuff here... **/
    },
    err=>{
      /** Stuff here... **/   //Should I stop here the whole thing here?
    })
  )
).subscribe(
  res=>{
    /** Stuff here... **/
  },
  err=>{
    /** Stuff here... **/
  })
)
```

#### Nested Subscribe:

*(I know it's not good practice)*

```
this.service.postFunction1(body1).subscribe(
  res=>{
    this.service.postFunction2(body2).subscribe(
     res=>{},
     err=>{}
    )
  },
  err=>{
    /** Stuff here... **/   //Should I stop here the whole thing here?
  })
)
```

Right now I'm calling them totally separately, because I don't have a clear view of how to call them together keeping that "if one fails, they both fail" in mind.

Maybe I just have to modify the backend and deal the 2 post requests as one function (1 endpoint), but I was curious whether there was a way to do it with separate requests.

Comment: Didn't the added answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [cancatMap()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html) for this. If you can arrange your API urls in an array and in a sequence you want to call the APIs, then you can use something like:

```
// consider these as API urls
urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3']

from(this.urls).pipe(
  concatMap((eachUrl, index) => {
    if (index === 1) {
      return throwError('Error in Second') // simulated error thrown by second API call
    }
    // simulated API calls, you just need to return this, not the error simulation
    // return your API call here and that's all under your concatMap()
    return of(eachUrl).pipe(tap(_ => console.log('API url invoked -> ', eachUrl)))
  })
).subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(`data in subscribe `, data);
}, (err) => {
  console.log(`error in subscribe: `, err)
})
```

You will see that the third API call will not trigger.

concatMap() will wait for a request to complete before sending the next.

See an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qo1luf?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by ?

> none of the requests actually goes through

The backend already received these requests, handle them and respond. They can not be undone.

Comment: Right, well I thought that maybe untiI I subscribe, the request could still be stopped. In my first example, I thought that if the second request (that I call inside the `pipe(map())`) failed, maybe I could stop the first request from being subscribed to later on. Or does that make no sense at all?

Comment: The only thing you can do is having requests in sequence, it means: you only send 2nd request if the 1st one is successful.